# sed edit specific columns and specific lines

Tags: sed

I have a file where the first character of each line is a format control character and I need to edit the format control characters as follows:

1. On the first line change `1` to `0`
2. All other lines change  `+` to `0`, `2` to `+`, and `3` to `+`

What is the `sed` code that can do this?

For example the input file has:

```
1 abcd efg
3 abcd 567
2 abcd 234
+ abcd 123
```

Desired result file:

```
0 abcd efg
+ abcd 567
+ abcd 234
0 abcd 123
```

Answer (score 2):

this is:

```
sed '1{y/1/0/;b}; y/+23/0++/'
```

or

```
sed '1y/1/0/; 1!y/+23/0++/'
```

If you want only the first char of each line, you need to do so:

```
sed '1/^1/s::0: ; 1!{ /^[+]/s::0:; /^2/s::+:; /^3/s::+:; }'
```

Comment: Need to be careful with `y`, since the questions sample output does not replace all occurrences of `2` with `+`.  `s` without the `g` flag is necessary.

Comment: ya -- I did not see that he wants to replace only the first char. In that case, indeed, y must be replaced by /^+/ s::0: ; /^2/ s::+: ; /^3/ s::+: ;

Answer (score 1):

The term 'control character' usually means 'character code between 0x00 and 0x1F', sometimes extended to include 0x7F, and sometimes 0x80 to 0x9F.  However, in context, I suspect you mean (on review) that the first character of the column needs to be changed.  In that case, this mildly revised script should do the trick; the revision adds the `^` to anchor the matches to the first character of each line.

```
sed -e '1s/^1/0/' -e '2,${s/^+/0/;s/^[23]/+/;}' "$@"
```

The first `-e` option changes 1 to 0 on the first line only.

The second `-e` deals with the other lines.  The first substitute deals with `+` to `0`; the second with `2` or `3` to `+`.

It could all be done with a single `-e` (or without an explicit `-e`), but the discussion is easier as written.

Comment: Note that `2` is not changed to `+` in the sample output.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan's solution is essentially correct, but applying multiple commands separated by `;` is not portable.  (In particular, BSD sed on OS X does not recognize that.)  For portability's sake, it would probably be better to write it as:

```
sed -e '1s/^1/0/' -e '1!s/^+/0/' -e '1!s/^[23]/+/'
```

or

```
sed -e '1s/^1/0/'  -e '1!{
s/^+/0/
s/^[23]/+/
}'
```

Comment: In general, I agree there are some quirks in the Mac OS X version of `sed`.  However, the code in my answer works fine with `/usr/bin/sed` on my Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
sed -e '1s/^1/0/' -e '1!s/^+/0/' -e '1!s/^[23]/+/'
```

The first part handles the first line, the next one changes the +, the last one handles 2 and 3. The exclamation mark means "Do this for lines other than the given one."